# Perform action after loading page with delay

Tags: javascript

I want to show a div but it has to show when the page is fully loaded, and then it has to wait 3 seconds.

So:

1. Load page...
2. Page loaded...
3. Wait 3 seconds...
4. Perform action.

How do I do this?

This is currently my code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    $("#logoResize").attr('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); -moz-transform:scale(1.25); -ms-transform:scale(1.25); -o-transform:scale(1.25); transform:scale(1.25);');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#logoResize").attr('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); -moz-transform:scale(1.25); -ms-transform:scale(1.25); -o-transform:scale(1.25); transform:scale(1.25);');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Does't work for me ... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Closing parenthesis was missing. Updated.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the job. Must wait 4 minutes to accept.. Please wait :D